# What is the punishment for homosexuals?

Tags: source-identification

I read in a book about the big sins (الكبائر) at one of the (local) masajids.  In the book it said that one should destroy the homosexuals by standing at a high place and throwing rocks on them, for that is how Loot's (لوط) peace be upon him people were destroyed.  What I would like to know is, is there any Hadith mentioning this? if so what is the authenticity?

Comment: your question is not clear.

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter what do you don't understand?

Comment: `I was looking through the contents and stopped and gone to a (chapter) about homosexuals (اللواط), in this (chapter)` are you refering to Quran here? `it said that what one should do is stand at a high place and through stones down, for that is how Loot's (لوط) peace be upon him people was destroyed` who said this? If you are referring to Quran already then hadith is not important.

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter I am referring to the book I was reading from.  I edited the question.

Comment: One should throw stones down from a high place with out any reason?

Comment: makes sense now but for every punishment one must be convicted first. We can't just throw someone with stone if *we* know he is homosexual.

Comment: I understand that :) my question is only about if there is a hadith about this, for there is no Ayah, and I want to know the authenticity.

Comment: Ayat al-rajm is a contentious subject. Some say it was a part of the Qur'an and others reject it.

Answer (score 2):

The only punishments for liwaT that I have come across are stoning to death, lashes (for non-penetrative or ghayr-muHsan), striking of the neck by the sword, being burnt alive and being thrown off a mountain with hands and feet tied. I have found no mention of stoning from a high place, or a specific manner of doing so. These are the references (Shi`i aHadith):

- [www.al-islam.org/greater_sins_complete](http://www.al-islam.org/greater_sins_complete/16.htm)
- [www.tashayyu.org](http://www.tashayyu.org/hadiths/hudud/sodomy)

The Hadith about being struck and then being burnt in the fire is SaHiH as per al-Majlisi's grading for the book, al-Kafi.

Comment: But these references aren't from the Quran or the Hadiths on Mohammad's(pbuh) life, and are merely human opinions.

Comment: I do not see the OP specifying anywhere in his post that he wants aHadith based on the definition of Hadith as you seem to have accepted. In the Ithna 3Ashari school, aHadith refers to all the sayings traced to either of the FOURTEEN ma`sumeen (as) - the Prophet (saww), his daughter FaTimah (as) and twelve Imams, beginning with 3Ali b. Abi Talib (as).

Comment: Also I just realised, what do you mean by "human opinions"? Was the Prophet (saww) non-human, ma`adh-Allah?

Comment: the Prophet wasn't expressing his human opinion, he was expressing what the Archangel Gabriel was telling him to say and do. The twelve Imams weren't messengers of Allah.

Comment: Interesting. So you believe that the Prophet (saww) has a "human" (fallible?) opinion and a "non-human" (you could simply say 'divine', you know) opinion? Is this your personal interpretation of Surat al-Najm, verses 3 and 4?

Comment: yes, Mohammad was a humanbeing like us, and therefore with an fallible opinion. But this isn't what he was expressing when he was told by the Archangel Gabriel what to say and do.